# How to truncate a column in a Pandas time series data frame so as to remove leading and trailing zeros?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following time series df in Pandas:

```
date          value
2015-01-01      0
2015-01-02      0
2015-01-03      0
2015-01-04      3
2015-01-05      0
2015-01-06      4 
2015-01-07      0
```

I would like to remove the leading and trailing zeroes, so as to have the following df:

```
date          value
2015-01-04      3
2015-01-05      0
2015-01-06      4
```

Simply dropping rows with 0s in them would lead to deleting the 0s in the middle as well, which I don't want.

I thought of writing a forward loop that starts from the first row and then continues until the first non 0 value, and a second backwards loop that goes back from the end and stops at the last non 0 value. But that seems like overkill, is there a more efficient way of doing so?

Answer (score 3):

General solution returned empty DataFrame, if all `0` values in data with cumulative sum of mask tested not equal `0` values and swapped values by `[::-1]` chained by `bitwise AND` and filtering by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
s = df['value'].ne(0)
df = df[s.cumsum().ne(0) & s[::-1].cumsum().ne(0)]
print (df)
         date  value
3  2015-01-04      3
4  2015-01-05      0
5  2015-01-06      4
```

---

If always at least one non `0` value is possible convert `0` to missing values and use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with [`DataFrame.first_valid_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.first_valid_index.html) and 
[`DataFrame.last_valid_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.last_valid_index.html):

```
s = df['value'].mask(df['value'] == 0)
df = df.loc[s.first_valid_index():s.last_valid_index()]
print (df)
         date  value
3  2015-01-04      3
4  2015-01-05      0
5  2015-01-06      4
```

Another idea is use [`DataFrame.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) or [`DataFrame.idxmin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmin.html):

```
s = df['value'].eq(0)
df = df.loc[s.idxmin():s[::-1].idxmin()]
print (df)
         date  value
3  2015-01-04      3
4  2015-01-05      0
5  2015-01-06      4
```

---

```
s = df['value'].ne(0)
df = df.loc[s.idxmax():s[::-1].idxmax()]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get a list of the indexes where value is > than 0, and then find the `min`.

```
data = [
    ['2015-01-01',      0],
    ['2015-01-02',      0],
    ['2015-01-03',      0],
    ['2015-01-04',      3],
    ['2015-01-05',      0],
    ['2015-01-06',      4]
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['date', 'value'])

print(min(df.index[df['value'] > 0].tolist()))
# 3
```

Then filter the main df like this:

```
df.iloc[3:]
```

Or even better:

```
df.iloc[min(df.index[df['value'] > 0].tolist()):]
```

And you get:

```
    date        value
3   2015-01-04  3
4   2015-01-05  0
5   2015-01-06  4
```